# Kylo security implementation in HDP KYLO sandbox?

Tags: security, kylo

I am trying to apply security in Kylo, such as the feed and category created by one user if it is not visible to other users.

Is it possible in Kylo HDP Sandbox?

If yes, what changes do I need to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via Kylo's [entity-level access control](https://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/AccessControl.html?#entity-level-authorization) mechanism. Below is an illustration to enable entity access for categories in Kylo sandbox.

**Step 1: Enable entity access control**

Update `kylo-services/conf/application.properties`

```
security.entity.access.controlled=true
security.auth.file.users=file:///opt/kylo/users.properties
security.auth.file.groups=file:///opt/kylo/groups.properties
```

**Step 2: Define users**

Create a file called `users.properties`, populate it and give proper permissions. The structure of each entry is `username=password`.

```
$ vi /opt/kylo/users.properties

#entries in file
dladmin=thinkbig
analyst=analyst
designer=designer
operator=operator

$ chown kylo:users /opt/kylo/users.properties
$ chmod 600 /opt/kylo/users.properties
```

**Step 3: Define groups**

Create a file called `groups.properties`, populate it and give proper permissions. The structure of each entry is `user=group memberships`.

```
$ vi /opt/kylo/groups.properties

#entries in file
dladmin=admin,user
analyst=analyst,user
designer=designer,user
operator=operations,user

$ chown kylo:users /opt/kylo/groups.properties
$ chmod 600 /opt/kylo/groups.properties
```

**Step 4: Restart Kylo**

```
$ /opt/kylo/stop-kylo-apps.sh
$ /opt/kylo/start-kylo-apps.sh
```

**Step 5: Log in as dladmin user (password: thinkbig)**

Create a category (say `sample_category`). Do not give any entity level permissions.

[image: category-creation-no-permissions]

**Step 6: Log in as operator user (password: operator)**

Look at the list of categories. `sample_category` is not visible since no permissions were given by the `dladmin` user.

[image: operator-cannot-see-category]

**Step 7: Log back in as dladmin user and give permissions**

Give `Editor` role to `Operations` group. The `operator` user is a member of `Operations` group.

[image: editor-role-to-operations-group]

**Step 8: Log back in as operator user**

Look at the list of categories. `sample_category` is now visible

[image]